# Sending OfficeJS 2D Array through Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, office-js

I'm trying to send a "large" table in OfficeJS:

#### functionfile.html loaded from manifest route

```
<script>
(function (){
"use strict";

Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#send-data-button").click(send_data);
    });
};

function send_data() {
    return Excel.run( function(context) {
    var data = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("SheetName")
                      .getRange("A1:K3673").load("values");

    return context.sync().then( function() {
        // 2d table is correctly seen
        // $("body").append(data.values);

        // Just gets lost in ajax call
        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: mysite,
           data: {"accessData": data.values},

         }).done( function(success) {
            $("body").append("All Done");

         }).fail( function(error) {
            $("body").append("Error == " + JSON.stringify(error));
         });

         return context.sync();
    });
    });
}
})();
</script>
<div> <button id="send-data-button"> Send </button></div>
```

However i'm not sure how to send this, on the backside I have a flask server catching the request and was hoping I could just use `pandas.read_json` but no matter how I try to send this i'm getting different errors.  Here's the printout of `flask.request` when `data.values[0][0]`:

```
CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([('update_date', '43191'), ('accessData', 'Channel')]), ImmutableMultiDict([])])
```

And when I try `data.values[0]` I get a list of values, which is what i'd expect

```
CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([('update_date', '43191'), ('accessData[]', 'Channel'), ... <All my column headers>, ImmutableMultiDict([])])
```

But when I try to send the 2D array with just `data.values` I get an error message in `ajax.fail`:

```
Error == {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

I also tried `JSON.stringify(data.values)` and got the same error message:

```
Error == {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

I even tried to take each column and convert them to some kind of list as nested keys inside `accessData` but I was getting the same error message.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell just from that snippet, but I think your issue might actually be scope. That ajax error typically indicates that the ajax request is getting interrupted (commonly by an unintended postback). In your case I think it's because your ajax seems to be relying on variables that are not passed in and may be undefined when your callback is returned.

Comment: Yeah i'm thinking either WSGI/Flask is limiting my request size.   If I just dump the contents into the actual addin `$("body").append(data.values)` then I can see the entire table as I would imagine.  But I still get an ajax error, with no error from server side so it must be angry.

Comment: Is it possible to try with a smaller, or even empty payload to test your size limit theory?

Comment: Yeah I tried it with `mysite.com/api?'data=%5B%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%2C+%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%5D'` and everything worked... Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should isolate the getting-data-from-Excel part from your ajax call part.  Right now, the two are intertwined, which makes it both harder to help debug, and just conceptually less clean.

For the Excel part, you should be able to do:

`function getExcelData(){
    return Excel.run( function(context) {
        var data = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("SheetName")
            .getRange("A1:K3673").load("values");
        return context.sync()
            .then(function() {
                return data.values;
            });
    })
}`

This will free you up to then do:

`getExcelData().then(function(values) {
       $.ajax(...)
    });`

Note that `range.values` returns just a regular 2D array, nothing special.  So you can try out your ajax call independently of the Excel call (which is yet another reason to separate those out)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I posted my entire code, but the more I play around with it i'm thinking my server side process is just dropping it for being to big of a payload as it works if I just dump it inside the content addin.